# JS to change img tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of java-script in one page. Working (this time :) )

When I add the following simple code everything stops working, is there a small type or something I am missing?

```
if(document.getElementById('checkBottom').checked)
{
     document.getElementById('preview_hl_front').src = "./assets/images/bottom---highligt-front.png";
{
else
{
     document.getElementById('preview_hl_front').src = "./assets/images/highligt-front.png";
}
```

Other components:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bottom" id="checkBottom" value="yes" data-preview="preview_bottom" onclick="validate()">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="preview">
        <img src="./assets/images/highligt-front.png" id="preview_hl_front" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to explain what "stops working" means.

Comment: highligt missing an h.  is this a spelling error in your code or are all your images spelled incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. you closed the `if` block with `{` instead of `}`
Change this:

```
if(document.getElementById('checkBottom').checked)
{
     document.getElementById('preview_hl_front').src = "./assets/images/bottom---highligt-front.png";
{
```

To this:

```
if(document.getElementById('checkBottom').checked)
{
     document.getElementById('preview_hl_front').src = "./assets/images/bottom---highligt-front.png";
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, so this took me a couple hours....
I wish we could solve all other 'real' problems in the world this fast.!
Thanks.

Comment: @Muiter yeah happens to us all, what editor are you using? most proper JS IDE's would of notify you about this.

Comment: I have been using Crimson Editor for as long as I can remember.

Comment: well, i don't know this one but you may want to take a look on `vsCode`, `Atom`, `SublimeText` ...